# RAID Controller / RAID Array question

Tags: hardware-raid, imaging

I have a question about my RAID controller. It's an Adaptec 2010s (onboard). I have 3 machines, all the same hardware. One is running, the others are down. If I pull my 4 SCSI hard disks out of the machine and I put them in the other machine will it then boot? Can it read the RAID array?

If I want to make an image of my server, how can I do that? Normally I use Acronis or Norton Ghost to make a image but I think Acronis and Ghost will not have drivers for my RAID controller. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the Adaptec 2010S in particular, but if there's an interface to import the existing array configuration from a group of disks then you'll probably be able to boot the disks you move. Some trashy old Adaptec controllers (I'm looking at you, AAA-131) were rock-stupid and wouldn't allow you to import an existing array without initializing it, but most sane controllers (LSI Logic, Mylex) will permit you to use an existing array. [Adaptec says you can](http://ask.adaptec.com/scripts/adaptec_tic.cfg/php.exe/enduser/std_adp.php?p_faqid=3294&p_created=1000248217&p_topview=1) do what you're looking for.

Generally I find disk-imaging of server computers to be evil. Having said that, though, if your imaging tool boots from MS-DOS (or some free analog thereof) and your RAID controller has a ROM BIOS on it (which it appears the 2010S does) you should be able to use the imaging tool. If it's Windows-based (something WindowsPE-based, etc) then you'll probably need to make a driver floppy or slipstream the drivers onto the boot media.